# Find all $m,n$ s.t. $3\mid 2^n-1$ and $\frac{2^n-1}{3} \mid 4m^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all $m,n\in \mathbb N$ such that  $3\mid 2^n-1$ and $$\frac{2^n-1}{3} \bigm\vert 4m^2+1$$

The first condition is easy. Just note that $ord_3(2)=2$, thus $$2^n\equiv 1\pmod 3\iff n=2a$$
Now we have to deal with the second condition $$4m^2+1\equiv 0 \left(\mod{\frac{4^a-1}{3}}\right)$$
but $4^a-1=3\sum4^{a-k}$, hence $$4m^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{\sum_{k=1}^a 4^{a-k}}$$
but this is a sum not a product so I can't use the Chinese Remainder Theorem on it.

Comment: Are you sure the formulation is correct?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It means that you might make an error copying the problem. The second part of it looks strange. For example if $n=2$, then $m$ is anything, if $n=4$, then $m\equiv 1,4 \pmod{5}$, etc.

Comment: Here is the source https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2113h1036423_1999_korean_math_olympiad -@markvs

Comment: That is not true. The source is a Korean math olympiad. Unlike you, the user in AoPS had decency to refer to his/her source.

Comment: Sorry, but now you know that there is no typo in my problem. Right?

Comment: No I do not know that. The person at AoPS probably made an error.

Comment: @markvs- Well, what about this https://imomath.com/othercomp/Kor/KorMOf99.pdf ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133709/discussion-between-markvs-and-yassir).

Answer (score 1):

First note that your request is to find:
$$\{(n,m)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N:3\mid(2^n-1)\land((2^n-1)/3\mid(4m^2+1))\}$$
while that in your link is required:
$$S=\{n\in\Bbb N:3\mid(2^n-1)\land\exists m\in\Bbb N((2^n-1)/3\mid(4m^2+1))\}$$

Let $p\gt 2$ be a prime number.
The following conditions are equivalent:

1. For every $r\gt 0$, there exists $m\gt 0$ such that $p^r\mid(4m^2+1)$
2. There exists $m\gt 0$ such that $p\mid(4m^2+1)$
3. $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

The equivalence between 1) and 2) follows from Hensel's Lemma.
The equivalence between 2) and 3) follows from properties of [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) $(-1|p)$.
Applying Chinese remainder theorem to 1), we get:

4. For an odd integer $d$, there exists $m\gt 0$ such that $d\mid(4m^2+1)$ if and only if every prime factor $p$ of $d$ satisfy $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

If $2\nmid a\geq 2$, then $3\mid(2^a+1)$, $2^a-1\equiv-1\pmod 4$ and
$$\frac{4^a-1}3=(2^a-1)\frac{2^a+1}3$$
hence $(4^a-1)/3$ has at least a prime factor $p$ with $p\equiv-1\pmod 4$, hence $2a\notin S$.
Consequently, if $a\in S$, then $a$, hence $n=2a$, is a power of $2$.
If $a=2^r$ with $r\geq 1$, then
$$\frac{4^a-1}3=\prod_{k=0}^{r-1}(4^{2^k}+1)$$
By 4), every prime factor $p$ of $(4^r-1)/3$ satisfy $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, hence $2a\in S$.